# How will be correct open new window from imported script (tkinter, python)?

Tags: python, tkinter

Widget tk.Entry from example_script.py do not save value 'textvariable' field.

example_script.py:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, text):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        textVar = tk.StringVar()
        textVar.set(text)
        entryVar = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=textVar).pack()
        self.pack()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    text = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
    for i in text:
        App(root, i)
    root.mainloop()
```

main_script.py:

```
import Tkinter import example_script as ex

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    Tkinter.Button(root, text='press', command=lambda: ex.main()).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

If I change row 'entryVar = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=textVar).pack()' to

```
entryVar = tk.Entry(self)
entryVar.pack()
entryVar.insert(0, text)
```

field's value is updated. Why?

How will be correct open new window from imported script? Tkinter.Toplevel() is not suitable. Now I use subprocess.Popen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create two instances of the `Tk` class in one program. Tkinter is not designed to work that way.

Comment: I know. Therefore, this different behavior is interesting. My story: there is a script that can not be changed. The script creates a window. Now I call it from other window (when button pressed) using module subprocess (Popen). Are there other ways?

Comment: What you are asking in your comment is a completely different question. If you're using popen to spawn another process, that's a completely different issue from the original question.

Comment: Sorry. Probably should have been split into two questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `entryVar = tk.Entry(self).pack()`, `entryVar` will be set to `None` because that is what `pack()` returns. When you call `pack` on a separate line, `entryVar` gets set to what you think it does.

Comment: Not this question. In case tk.Entry(self, textvariable=textVar).pack() or entryVar = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=textVar); entryVar.pack() text 'text1', 'text2' etc is not displayed. In case usage entryVar.insert(0, text) text is displayed.